# Conditional preprocessing puzzle

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem where I can't seem to get conditional #define preprocessors to work correctly.  For example:

```
#define WIN32_BUILD
#ifdef WIN32_BUILD
  #define PCH "stdafx.h"
#else
  #define PCH "xyz.h"
#endif

#include PCH
```

If I use this form, the compiler tells me that it can't find 'stdafx.h'.  OK, that seems odd, so if I change the code to....

```
#define WIN32_BUILD
#ifdef WIN32_BUILD
  #define PCH "xyz.h"
#else
  #define PCH "stdafx.h"
#endif

#include PCH
```

Then the file defined in PCH gets picked up and everything compiles fine.  This seems odd to me, almost like the preprocessor is ignoring the #if directives and just using all the #defines that it encounters.

Obviously I am doing something wrong, and I was hoping that someone could help me understand this.

Comment: I think you want `#else`, not `#elif`. You don't have a second condition, it's just a normal 'else'.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl: Wasn't sure if this was the cause of the problem in question, was more something I noted looking at the code. But I'll add as an answer anyway if it seems to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: The same thing happens with #else.

Comment: Then I will remove my answer - the comment has served its purpose, and answer is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 3):

When a project has the precompiled header feature turned on the preprocessor ignores everything that comes before #include "stdafx.h"

So your #define statements are ignored.

Comment: Oh, that seems weird.  What can I do about it ?

Comment: In the project settings for precompiled header you can turn the feature off, or you can change the name of the precompiled header file to xyz.h and eliminate all define/ifdef lines that you have before the #include

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR; `#define` defines the symbol, `#ifdef` tests if the symbol is defined not whether it has a value.

```
#define WIN32_BUILD
```

This defines a pre-processor token, WIN32_BUILD. The token has no value. Anywhere you use the token 'WIN32_BUILD' the pre-processor will substitute the empty string, i.e. nothing.

```
#ifdef WIN32_BUILD
```

This checks if the pre-processor token WIN32_BUILD is defined. It is, you just defined it.

```
#ifdef WIN32_BUILD
// true - this code is included.
#define PCH "stdafx.h"
```

This defines the pre-processor token, PCH, and assigns it the value "stdafx.h"

```
#else
#define PCH "xyz.h"
#endif
```

This code is ignored, because WIN32_BUILD *was* defined.

It looks as though you were expecting 'ifdef' to only evaluate to true if the expression was not defined /to/ something.

```
#define a
#define b SOMETHING

#ifdef a
// you are expecting this to be ignored
#endif

#ifdef b
// and expecting this not to be ignored
#endif
```

`#ifdef` and `#if defined(...)` do the same thing.

```
#define a
#define b SOMETHING

#if defined(a) && defined(b)
// this code will be evaluated, both tokens are defined.
#endif
```

This feature of pre-processor tokens is often used to support conditional functionality:

```
#if HAVE_CPP11_OVERRIDE_KEYWORD
#define OVERRIDE_FN override
#else
#define OVERRIDE_FN
#endif

struct A {
    virtual void foo() {}
};

struct B : public A {
    void foo() OVERRIDE_FN {}
};
```

In the above code, the `override` keyword is only added if the system supports it (determined outside of the code).

So a compiler with `override` sees

```
struct B : public A {
    void foo() override {}
};
```

a compiler without it sees

```
struct B : public A {
    void foo() {}
};
```

Note: The opposite of "ifdef" is "ifndef":

```
#define a
#define b SOMETHING
#undef c
//#define d // << we didn't define it.

int main() {

#ifdef a
#pramga message("a is defined")
#else
#pramga message("a is UNdefined")
#endif

#ifdef b
#pragma message("b is defined")
#else
#pramga message("b is UNdefined")
#endif

#ifdef c
#pramga message("c is defined")
#endif
#else
#pramga message("c is UNdefined")
#endif

#ifdef d
#pramga message("d is defined")
#endif
#else
#pramga message("d is UNdefined")
#endif

#ifndef d
#pragma message("d is not defined")
#endif

#ifndef a
#pragma message("a is not defined")
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

You can assign a pre-processor token numeric values and test them with `#if`

```
#if _MSC_VER
#define WIN32_BUILD 1
#else
#define WIN32_BUILD 0
#endif

#if WIN32_BUILD
#include <Windows.h>
#endif
```

But, especially when doing cross-platform programming, people tend to use `ifdef` variants rather than numeric checks, because the value checks require you to explicitly ensure all of the tokens are defined with a value. It's a lot easier just to only define them when you need them.